# What's the best way to add click listener to my JavaScript tab bar?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am planning to implement a tab bar module in JavaScript.

I want to create a **TabBar** every time the page loaded, and then put two **Tabs** into it.

The problem is, what's the best way to add **click event** to my tabs?

Here's my code:

```
 // A tab in tab bar.
 Tab = function(titleID, contentID) {
   this.title = document.getElementById(titleID);
   this.content = document.getElementById(contentID);
 }

 Tab.prototype.show = function() {
   this.title.className = "title-bg-active";
 }

 Tab.prototype.hide = function() {
   this.title.className = "";
 }


 // Tab bar contains several tabs.
 TabBar = function() {
   this.tabs = [];
 }

 TabBar.prototype.add = function(tab) {
   // TODO add click listener to tab
   this.tabs.push(tab);
 }

 TabBar.prototype.open = function(tab) {
   for(var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
     if(tab.title == this.tabs[i].title) {
       tab.show();
     }else{
       tab.hide();
     }
   }
 }

 window.onload = function(){
   tb = new TabBar();
   tb.add(new Tab("famous", "famous-content"));
   tb.add(new Tab("recently", "recently-content"));
 }
```

I really don't want to use jQuery or any other library, thanks!

**EDIT:**
I also need to notify other tabs to close, how can I do that in `onclick`? I think the tab should hold a `tabbar`, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your tab constructor, add `this.title.onclick = this.onclick`, then define onclick in the prototype:

```
Tab.prototype.onclick = function(event) {
    // handle click
    // 'this' will hold the clicked element
}
```

---

Considering your update, this could work:

```
TabBar.prototype.add = function(tab) {
    var bar = this;
    tab.title.onclick = (function(clickedTab){
        return function() {
            // Hide all tabs
            for(var i=0; i<bar.tabs.length; i++) {
                bar.tabs[i].hide();
            }

            // Show clicked tab
            clickedTab.show();
        }
    }(tab));
    this.tabs.push(tab);
}
```